# What are the possible locations that a game can store coins/gold count?

Tags: applications, root-access

I've a rooted phone along with FX File Explorer and Root add-on. I also have the following apps installed on the phone:

- SB Game Hacker
- Game Killer

When trying to modify the values of gold/coins in game, I've come across 3 use cases so far.

**Case 1:**

- I open the game and note down the current value of coins I have.
- Then I open the SB/GameKiller app and search for that value.
- Then I go back into the game and decrease/increase the coins.
- Back to the SB/GameKiller app and re-scan for the modified value.
- I repeat the process until I'm down to about 5-10 results after which I modify the value in SB/GameKiller app to a value of my liking.
- After this, when I go back into the game, the new value gets reflected
- SUCCESS

**Case 2:**

- Case 1 fails (where the final modified value doesn't get reflected in the game).
- So I go to `/data/data/<game package folder>/` folder.
- I usually find a `.json` file which contains the value of coins/gold.
- I change the value and save the `.json` file and go back into the game.
- SUCCESS

**Case 3:**

- Case 1 fails and I do not find any `.json` file
- I try to look for a database folder/file inside the same `/data/data/<game package folder>/` path but do not find one

In this case, where can a game be possibly storing this value and fetching it from? It can't be a server because I play the game without being connected to the internet. So my best assumption is that the value is stored locally.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend decompiling the apk using apktool or any other tool.
Then search in .java files for strings containing "\" or "/" .
It's time taking but worth a try.

Answer (score -2):

In media,simcard,sdcard,data,dcim,plyprfs,appl.data,android,.profig.os,
com.facebook.orca-katana,it's a virtual file there's a bunch of places it could be hiding ✌

Comment: I doubt that. It was standard installation (not on the sd card but internal memory) so I don't think it would be anywhere except the `/data/data/` folder.